# RestKit: Mapping multiple attributes to a single array

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I have a Objective C class that has the following attributes

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *companies;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *users;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *tags;
```

These arrays are collections of other objects (instances of Company,User and Tag class).
I need to create a **requestDescriptorWithMapping** for the POST request which
will put all the members of the arrays into a single one named params with the following
structure:

```
{ name: "Test", 
  params: [
    {param:'company', values:['CompanyName1','CompanyName2'..],
    {param:'users', values:['UserName1','UserName2'..]
  ]
}
```

What would be the best way to go here? I'm testing RKBlockValueTransformer but
so far no success. I can create this array manually by creating three NSMutableDictionaries but wanted to check is there a better way to this.

Comment: Show your block transformer and how close it gets you to what you want. There is no magic way to get to the representation you want as you are creating new data for the 'param' value.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
[@{ @"name": self.name, 
   @"params": @[
    @{@"param":@"company", values:[self.companies valueForKey:@"name"]}
    @{@"param":@"users", values:[self.users valueForKey:@"name"]}
  ]
} mutableCopy]
```

Assuming you Company and User classes have a name property. And if you're not using ARC you'll need to autorelease the result of `mutableCopy`

Comment: right, this is the 'manual' way. Is there a way to integrate this into RestKit ?

Comment: What do you mean integrate into RestKit?

Comment: e.g can I use that dictionary here:
RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[self class]];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:thatDictionary]; ?